# vitamin D in mushrooms

Tags: microbiology, plant-physiology, vitamins, food-chemistry

How could I test vitamin D levels in mushrooms? (I am a high school student, our lab is pretty modern, but my resources are limited)
I found an article about it (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jfq/2020/8869279/) but I cannot understand it. Also, it is on a few different types of vitamin D. I want to test the active(usable?) vitamin D amount in different grown mushrooms.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In addition, we have no idea what "pretty modern" means — if you want useful answers you need to put in more effort on your part. Do you have access to an HPLC/FPLC machine or any kind of set up for doing column chromatography? In not, then the paper you linked is of no help to you. Have you researched what forms of vitamin D are "active"? If not, that would seem to be your first step — I suggest editing that information into your question along with what you can find on your own about methods for detecting those compounds.